# Ignore Parent Elements Margin

Tags: html, css

I am trying to span an image the width of a parent element, however the parent element has a `margin: 10px;` This means when I set

```
#parent img {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%
}
```

This only stretches the image to the width of the parent... minus 10px on either side. How can I set the image to the FULL width of the parent, ignoring the margin?

Comment: But the `margin` isn't a part of the element; it's spacing between that element and its neighbours (or I'm *really* misunderstanding something).

Comment: Your margin shouldn't be effecting this. Margins are outside of the box and padding is inside of the box. Could you provide a jsfiddle replicating your problem?

Comment: Are you using box-sizing:border-box? Then the margin is a part of the interior div, but the image is set to absolute. Is the parent set to position:relative? To help troubleshoot, hit F12 in your browser to inspect the elements, and view the applied styles. The current code doesn't offer enough info to solve the problem. We'll need more code, and a JSFiddle would be great.

Comment: can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.
Css only allows an element to modify itself within it's parent's constraint.

As a way to get around this you can try changing the position attribute of the element to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#parent img {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height: auto;
width: calc(100% + 10px);
```

}